# Why I can't display an js error alert in updatepanel page from class?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a radiobutton (in updatepanel) and in checkchanged event I'm displaying a message to user. But div is in masterpage and page is not rendering, that's why I can't display message.
Is it possible to solve this? Btw I'm using class to display messages.
Here is my codes.

```
public static void setError(System.Web.UI.Page p, string title, string error, string type)
    {
        Literal literal = p.Master.FindControl("ltMessage") as Literal;

        if (type == "error")
        {
            literal.Text = "<div id=\"alertError\" style=\"display:none; color:#fff; text-align:center; padding: 8px 10px 9px; width:auto; position:relative; background:#cc0000;\"><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + error + "</p></div>";
            //literal.Text = "<div id=\"alert\" class=\"error message\"><h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + error + "</p></div>";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("$(function() { ");
            sb.Append(" $('#alertError').toggle({");
            sb.Append("    width: 400");
            sb.Append(" });");
            sb.Append("});");

            if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is Page)
            {
                Page pa = (Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;

                if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(pa) != null)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(pa, typeof(Page), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
                }
                else
                {
                    pa.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I put my div in updatepanel which was in the masterpage. And now it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how you are calling that setError. But `$(function() {...})` is a synonym to 
`$(document).ready(function(){...})` which is called only after page is loaded. UpadtePanel is doing an AJAX call and will not run `$(document).ready` event. Try code below:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" $('#alertError').toggle({");
sb.Append("    width: 400");
sb.Append(" });");
```

This should work if you are doing correctly everything else.